# Subscript error when trying to get keyboard frame?

Tags: swift

I am trying to get the keyboard frame from keyboard notfication. But I am getting the error "[NSObject:AnyObject] does not have any membership subscript"

I am using the following code.

```
  if keyboardNotification != nil {

        let userInfo = keyboardNotification!.userInfo


        let animationDuration: NSTimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as NSNumber).doubleValue()

        let keyboardScreenBeginFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue()

        let keyboardScreenEndFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`notification.userInfo` is `[NSObject : AnyObject]?`.

So, try this

```
if let userInfo = keyboardNotification.userInfo {

    let animationDuration        = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).doubleValue()
    let keyboardScreenBeginFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    let keyboardScreenEndFrame   = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

}
```